# How do you list the currently available objects in the current scope in ruby?

Tags: ruby, introspection, irb

I'm new to ruby and I'm playing around with the IRB.

I found that I can list methods of an object using the ".methods" method, and that self.methods sort of give me what I want (similar to Python's dir(**builtins**)?), but how can I find the methods of a library/module I've loaded via include and require?

```
irb(main):036:0* self.methods
=> ["irb_pop_binding", "inspect", "taguri", "irb_chws", "clone", "irb_pushws", "public_methods", "taguri=", "irb_pwws",
"public", "display", "irb_require", "irb_exit", "instance_variable_defined?", "irb_cb", "equal?", "freeze", "irb_context
", "irb_pop_workspace", "irb_cwb", "irb_jobs", "irb_bindings", "methods", "irb_current_working_workspace", "respond_to?"
, "irb_popb", "irb_cws", "fg", "pushws", "conf", "dup", "cwws", "instance_variables", "source", "cb", "kill", "help", "_
_id__", "method", "eql?", "irb_pwb", "id", "bindings", "send", "singleton_methods", "popb", "irb_kill", "chws", "taint",
 "irb_push_binding", "instance_variable_get", "frozen?", "irb_source", "pwws", "private", "instance_of?", "__send__", "i
rb_workspaces", "to_a", "irb_quit", "to_yaml_style", "irb_popws", "irb_change_workspace", "jobs", "type", "install_alias
_method", "irb_push_workspace", "require_gem", "object_id", "instance_eval", "protected_methods", "irb_print_working_wor
kspace", "irb_load", "require", "==", "cws", "===", "irb_pushb", "instance_variable_set", "irb_current_working_binding",
 "extend", "kind_of?", "context", "gem", "to_yaml_properties", "quit", "popws", "irb", "to_s", "to_yaml", "irb_fg", "cla
ss", "hash", "private_methods", "=~", "tainted?", "include", "irb_cwws", "irb_change_binding", "irb_help", "untaint", "n
il?", "pushb", "exit", "irb_print_working_binding", "is_a?", "workspaces"]
irb(main):037:0>
```

I'm used to python, where I use the dir() function to accomplish the same thing:

```
>>> dir()
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__name__', '__package__']
>>>
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

[ObjectSpace.each_object](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/classes/ObjectSpace.html#M000928) could be what you are looking for.

To get a list of included modules you could use [Module.included_modules](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Module.html#M001697).

You can also check if an object responds to a method on a case-by-case basis using [object.respond_to?](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Object.html#M000333).

Answer (score 49):

I'm not entirely sure of what you mean by the 'current objects'. You can iterate over ObjectSpace, as has been mentioned already. But here are a few other methods.

```
local_variables
instance_variables
global_variables

class_variables
constants
```

There's one gotcha. They must be called at the right scopes. So right in IRB, or in an object instance or at class scope (so everywhere, basically) you can call the first 3.

```
local_variables #=> ["_"]
foo = "bar"
local_variables #=> ["_", "foo"]
# Note: the _ variable in IRB contains the last value evaluated
_ #=> "bar"

instance_variables  #=> []
@inst_var = 42
instance_variables  #=> ["@inst_var"]

global_variables    #=> ["$-d", "$\"", "$$", "$<", "$_", ...]
$"                  #=> ["e2mmap.rb", "irb/init.rb", "irb/workspace.rb", ...]
```

But umm, what if you want your program to actually evaluate them without needing you to type them manyally? The trick is eval.

```
eval "@inst_var" #=> 42
global_variables.each do |v|
  puts eval(v)
end
```

The last 2 of the 5 mentioned at the beginning must be evaluated at the module level (a class is a descendant of a module, so that works).

```
Object.class_variables #=> []
Object.constants #=> ["IO", "Duration", "UNIXserver", "Binding", ...]

class MyClass
  A_CONST = 'pshh'
  class InnerClass
  end
  def initialize
    @@meh = "class_var"
  end
end

MyClass.constants           #=> ["A_CONST", "InnerClass"]
MyClass.class_variables     #=> []
mc = MyClass.new
MyClass.class_variables     #=> ["@@meh"]
MyClass.class_eval "@@meh"  #=> "class_var"
```

Here's are a few more tricks to explore in different directions

```
"".class            #=> String
"".class.ancestors  #=> [String, Enumerable, Comparable, ...]
String.ancestors    #=> [String, Enumerable, Comparable, ...]

def trace
  return caller
end
trace #=> ["(irb):67:in `irb_binding'", "/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby...", ...]
```

Answer (score 6):

The `dir()` method is [not clearly defined](http://www.python.org/doc/2.5.2/lib/built-in-funcs.html)...

> **Note:** Because `dir()` is supplied
>   primarily as a convenience for use at
>   an interactive prompt, it tries to
>   supply an interesting set of names
>   more than it tries to supply a
>   rigorously or consistently defined set
>   of names, and its detailed behavior
>   may change across releases.

...but we can create a close approximation in Ruby. Let's make a method that will return a sorted list of all methods added to our scope by included modules. We can get a list of the modules that have been included by using the `included_modules` method.

Like `dir()`, we want to ignore the "default" methods (like `print`), and we also want to focus on the "interesting" set of names. So, we will ignore methods in `Kernel`, and we will only return methods that were defined directly in the modules, ignoring inherited methods. We can accomplish the later by passing `false` into the `methods()` method. Putting it all together we get...

```
def included_methods(object=self)
  object = object.class if object.class != Class
  modules = (object.included_modules-[Kernel])
  modules.collect{ |mod| mod.methods(false)}.flatten.sort
end
```

You can pass it a class, an object, or nothing (it defaults to the current scope). Let's try it out...

```
irb(main):006:0> included_methods
=> []
irb(main):007:0> include Math
=> Object
irb(main):008:0> included_methods
=> ["acos", "acosh", "asin", "asinh", "atan", "atan2", "atanh", "cos", "cosh", "erf", "erfc", "exp", "frexp", "hypot", "ldexp", "log", "log10", "sin", "sinh", "sqrt", "tan", "tanh"]
```

---

`dir()` also includes locally defined variables, and that's an easy one. Just call...

```
local_variables
```

...unfortunately, we can't just add the `local_variables` call to `included_methods` because it would give us the variables that are local to the `included_methods` method, and that wouldn't be very useful. So, if you want local variables included with the included_methods, just call...

```
 (included_methods + local_variables).sort
```

Comment: ok, I'm learning slowly.  This brings on my next question, what's the difference between "include" and "require"?  I'll go do some reading, but how can methods be seen which were loaded via "require"?

Comment: An include will add the constants, methods, and module variables to the current scope. It is typically used to add functionality to a class. 

A require loads another ruby file (if it hasn't already been loaded). If you want to load it (even if it's already loaded) use the "load" method instead.

Comment: Typically a required file will load a class. For example require 'foo' will load the Foo classs. So, you can get a list of methods in that class by doing Foo.methods(false). If the required file is just a bunch of methods: orig = Object.private_methods; require 'foo'; p Object.private_methods - orig

Answer (score 5):

I wrote a gem for that:

```
$ gem install method_info
$ rvm use 1.8.7 # (1.8.6 works but can be very slow for an object with a lot of methods)
$ irb
> require 'method_info'
> 5.method_info
::: Fixnum :::
%, &, *, **, +, -, -@, /, <, <<, <=, <=>, ==, >, >=, >>, [], ^, abs,
div, divmod, even?, fdiv, id2name, modulo, odd?, power!, quo, rdiv,
rpower, size, to_f, to_s, to_sym, zero?, |, ~
::: Integer :::
ceil, chr, denominator, downto, floor, gcd, gcdlcm, integer?, lcm,
next, numerator, ord, pred, round, succ, taguri, taguri=, times, to_i,
to_int, to_r, to_yaml, truncate, upto
::: Precision :::
prec, prec_f, prec_i
::: Numeric :::
+@, coerce, eql?, nonzero?, pretty_print, pretty_print_cycle,
remainder, singleton_method_added, step
::: Comparable :::
between?
::: Object :::
clone, to_yaml_properties, to_yaml_style, what?
::: MethodInfo::ObjectMethod :::
method_info
::: Kernel :::
===, =~, __clone__, __id__, __send__, class, display, dup, enum_for,
equal?, extend, freeze, frozen?, hash, id, inspect, instance_eval,
instance_exec, instance_of?, instance_variable_defined?,
instance_variable_get, instance_variable_set, instance_variables,
is_a?, kind_of?, method, methods, nil?, object_id, pretty_inspect,
private_methods, protected_methods, public_methods, respond_to?, ri,
send, singleton_methods, taint, tainted?, tap, to_a, to_enum, type,
untaint
 => nil
```

I am working on an improvement of passing options and settings defaults, but for now I would suggest you add the following to your .irbrc file:

```
require 'method_info'
MethodInfo::OptionHandler.default_options = {
 :ancestors_to_exclude => [Object],
 :enable_colors => true
}
```

This enables colours and hides the methods that every object has, since you're usually not interested in those.

Comment: I'm guessing that's not really what the question was about but oh jeebus is this ever what I needed for irb.  The extensive use of mixins leading to way too many methods makes ruby libraries much harder to explore than python's, but this should very nicely help to sort through that.  Now I just need a replacement for help() that's just as good.

Answer (score 3):

What about:

```
Object.constants.select{|x| eval(x.to_s).class == Class}
```

That lists available classes for me. I am not ruby expert and I was being dropped at a ruby console with no idea of what classes were at hand. That one liner was a start.

Comment: This made my day. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

To access all object instances in ruby you use ObjectSpace

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/classes/ObjectSpace.html#M000928

However, this is considered slow (even for ruby), and may not be enabled in some interpreters (e.g. jRuby can disable ObjectSpace as it is much faster relying in the jvm for gc without needing to track this stuff in jRuby).

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the .methods messages to the library/module even before loading it, to see all the available methods. Doing `self.methods` just returns all the methods that the Object object contains. You can see this by doing `self.class`. So let's say you want to see all the methods in the File module. You simply do `File.methods` and you'll get a list of all the methods that exist in the File module. This, perhaps, isn't what you want, but it should  be somewhat helpful.